# Angular2 + Google Charts. How to integrate Google Charts in Angular2?

Tags: angular, google-visualization

I want to integrate Google Charts in my Angular2 application.
What is the way to do this?
Is there any examples available?

I tried to load the package like Google Charts is demoed but I had problems with the loading.
I tried angular2-google-chart... but did not manage to get it to work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: Can you put down the code that you tired?

Answer (score 26):

Here is how I solved it.

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleChartComponent} from './ChartComponent.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'evolution',
  template: `
    <div class="four wide column center aligned">
        <div id="chart_divEvolution" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class EvolutionComponent extends GoogleChartComponent {
  private options;
  private data;
  private chart;
  constructor(){
    console.log("Here is EvolutionComponent")
  }

  drawGraph(){
    console.log("DrawGraph Evolution...");  
    this.data = this.createDataTable([
      ['Evolution', 'Imports', 'Exports'],
      ['A', 8695000, 6422800],
      ['B', 3792000, 3694000],
      ['C', 8175000, 800800]
    ]);

    this.options = {
      title: 'Evolution, 2014',
      chartArea: {width: '50%'},
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Value in USD',
        minValue: 0
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Members'
      }
    };

    this.chart = this.createBarChart(document.getElementById('chart_divEvolution'));
    this.chart.draw(this.data, this.options);
  }
}
```

---

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
declare var google:any;
@Component({
  selector: 'chart'
})
export class GoogleChartComponent implements OnInit {
  private static googleLoaded:any;

  constructor(){
      console.log("Here is GoogleChartComponent")
  }

  getGoogle() {
      return google;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit');
    if(!GoogleChartComponent.googleLoaded) {
      GoogleChartComponent.googleLoaded = true;
      google.charts.load('current',  {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
    }
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(() => this.drawGraph());
  }

  drawGraph(){
      console.log("DrawGraph base class!!!! ");
  }

  createBarChart(element:any):any {
      return new google.visualization.BarChart(element);
  }

  createDataTable(array:any[]):any {
      return google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);
  }
}
```

Now all you need to do is add this to your index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. However I do have couple of questions- 1. In your example, you have used BarChart, but where I can find list of chart types supported other than BarChart, LineChart, BubbleChart, ScatterChart and PieChart? 2. Does Google supports multiple charts like Bar, Line and Bubble chart on same canvas (similar to any trading website eg. Google Finance or Yahoo Finance)?

Comment: I'm happy if this was useful. I used the above class in my projects as a based class for other subclass which actually use the other chart type. Look at the doc at [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) for all the charts available.

Comment: Thanks for reference :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. Do you know how to make the chart responsive? Thanks!

Comment: I would keep the base component off any specific chart method. I think createbarchart should be in the children classes.

Comment: and also, I had to add `template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'` in the @component declaration of GoogleChartComponent

Comment: hello @BuckBazooka, I have used this code and implemented map. It worked well but I am not able use handler and get the selected marker details. I need to perform action once user selects any marker.

Comment: Is it possible to implement the google map chart like the second last image in the below link?https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/11042288/25892861/5c489e74-3593-11e7-8384-d6e48c6b2bf1.png

Comment: Great share. Thanks

Comment: what is the advantage of GoogleChartComponent ? We can use EvolutionComponent with declare var google:any;

Answer (score 5):

```
//in index.html add
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

33.5KB loaded from google servers to your app.

now add

```
declare var google:any;
```

to your  component and add your google chart code in ngOnInit.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var google:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-charts',
  templateUrl: './charts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./charts.component.css']
})
export class ChartsComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { 

}

ngOnInit() {

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
}

}
```

additional 35.8KB loaded from google servers when 'corechart' is loaded.

add this to your components html

`<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>`

A better approach would be to use ViewChild instead of `document.getElementById('piechart')` in component ts file.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is suited if you are using routing. You can create a `Resolver` that will initialize and resolve the `google` object, which you can inject into your component.

First you need to add the below line to the end of index.html

```
// index.html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Then you need to create a `Resolver` say, named `GoogleChartResolver`.

```
// shared/google-chart.resolver.ts
declare const google: any;

@Injectable()
export class GoogleChartResolver implements Resolve<any>{

  private static googleChartLoaded: boolean = false;
  constructor() {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    if(GoogleChartResolver.googleChartLoaded){
      return Observable.of(google);
    } else {
      return Observable.create(function (observer: Observer<any>) {

        google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(() => {
          observer.next(google);
          observer.complete();
          GoogleChartResolver.googleChartLoaded = true;
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

For every route and component you need an instance of `google`, you can add the below lines. You need to add the `GoogleChartResolver` to the list of Observables to be resolved for the route,

```
// app-routing.module.ts
{path: 'my-path', component: MyComponent, resolve: {google: GoogleChartResolver}}
```

In the `MyComponent` you can inejct `ActivatedRoute` and get the instance of `google` from the snapshot

```
// my.component.ts
private google: any;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.google = this.route.snapshot.data.google;
  drawChart(this.google)
}
```

All the dependent resources for the Google charts will be loaded during the first time you try to resolve the Resolver (here, the first time you visit `/my-path`). On subsequent resolutions, already resolved object is returned (no resource fetch required). Also this approach loads all Chart packages at once.
If you need to optimize further, you can load different chart packages using different resolvers, but that may be an overkill, a solution for this will be, instead of creating `Resolver` classes, you can achieve route `resolve` functionality using method reference (say create a static method in a service which does the same thing).

Comment: awesome. this is the best way, imho.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for component like using please refer below ng2-google-charts.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-google-charts .
It internally uses the loader.js google library to render library.
You can use configuration for the charts through inputs.