# How to group chart labels together?

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I've got a chart to display data from the current quarter and previous quarter, but I also show it to the month. Here is an image of what I'm trying to do:[image]

I'm not sure how to do this or if it's even possible.  I'm currently using ng2-charts (which is based off of Chart.js) but I'm open to any open-source charting platform that works with Angular 2

Answer (score 1):

This library is what you are looking for `angular2-chartjs2`

https://github.com/evoila/angular2-chartjs2

Comment: That seems very similar to ng2-charts.  Can chartjs do what I'm looking for though?  I'm reading their docs now and don't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use highcharts with Angular2 then refer this- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts

PrimeNG charts can be an alternative- http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/barchart

Another option is Google Charts. Refer this - [Angular2 + Google Charts. How to integrate Google Charts in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542408/angular2-google-charts-how-to-integrate-google-charts-in-angular2)

Comment: Interesting, thank you.  I'm currently trying to get highcharts to load but I'm getting an error about `highcharts/highstock.src.js` not found.  

I've looked at PrimeNG but haven't found anything about the nested labels like I asked in the question. Google Charts looks great too but I can't find anything about nested labels.

Comment: For highcharts error, you need to refer highcharts as well as highstocks. hence make sure you have added below map in your systemjs.config.js
    'angular2-highcharts':        'https://cdn.rawgit.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/0.1.0/dist', 
    'highcharts/highstock.src':   'https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts-dist/v4.2.1/highstock.js'

Comment: For Google charts, available configuration options are here - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#configuration-options